# mysql how to get this result from timestamp field

Tags: mysql

I have a table something like this that hold a users login and logout times :

```
----------------------------------------------
name        |date       |timestamp   |action
----------------------------------------------
Philip      |2017-05-08 |1494225926  |login
Anna        |2017-05-08 |1494229108  |login
Laura       |2017-05-08 |1494232336  |login
Gerry       |2017-05-08 |1494232431  |login
Anna        |2017-05-08 |1494243781  |logout
Anna        |2017-05-08 |1494246660  |login
Laura       |2017-05-08 |1494247039  |logout
Philip      |2017-05-08 |1494248271  |logout
Laura       |2017-05-08 |1494249980  |login
Philip      |2017-05-08 |1494252177  |login
Laura       |2017-05-08 |1494255182  |logout
Laura       |2017-05-08 |1494256117  |login
Anna        |2017-05-08 |1494259279  |logout
Philip      |2017-05-08 |1494262771  |logout
Philip      |2017-05-08 |1494262775  |login
Gerry       |2017-05-08 |1494262821  |logout
Laura       |2017-05-08 |1494262822  |logout
Philip      |2017-05-08 |1494262886  |logout
```

I'm trying to create a query that would tell me who was logged in at a time specified by a timestamp (i.e. 1494248400) .. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE action = 'login' and `timestamp` <= 1494248400
AND name NOT IN (
    SELECT name FROM test WHERE action = 'logout' and `timestamp` <= 1494248400
)
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c51a7/4/0)**.

**Update**

To get all the users who logged out but logged back in again, you can use `GROUP BY` with condition, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT name, max(`timestamp`) as ts
 FROM test WHERE action = 'login' and `timestamp` <= 1494248400
 GROUP BY name ) t1
WHERE t1.name NOT IN (
   SELECT name FROM test WHERE action = 'logout' 
   AND `timestamp` <= 1494248400 AND timestamp >= t1.ts
  );
```

Here's the updated **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c51a7/8/0)**.

Comment: does MySQL support EXCEPT ?

Comment: Changed to `NOT EXISTS`, try now?

Comment: that gives empty result

Comment: @mrsmith updated the query and attached a working example (fiddle), try now?

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is working but not producing the result I require, this is excluding anyone who logged out before '1494248400' even if they had logged back in before '1494248400'

Comment: @mrsmith added another query.

Comment: Great this seems to work now ! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You can accept the answer as correct if it has helped you.